# Kubernetes does not trigger autoscale on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

For some reason Kubernetes 1.6.2 does not trigger autoscaling on Google Container Engine.

I have a `someservice` definition with the following resources and rolling update:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: someservice
  labels:
    layer: backend
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 160
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 100%
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate  
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: someservice
        layer: backend        
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: someservice
        image: eu.gcr.io/XXXXXX/someservice:v1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 20Gi        
          requests:
            cpu: 400m
            memory: 18Gi
     <.....>
```

After changing image version, the new instance cannot start:

```
$ kubectl -n dev get pods -l name=someservice
NAME                      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
someservice-2595684989-h8c5d   0/1       Pending   0          42m
someservice-804061866-f2trc    1/1       Running   0          1h

$ kubectl -n dev describe pod someservice-2595684989-h8c5d

Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubObjectPath   Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------          -------
  43m       43m     4   default-scheduler           Warning     FailedScheduling    No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: Insufficient cpu (4), Insufficient memory (3).
  43m       42m     6   default-scheduler           Warning     FailedScheduling    No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: Insufficient cpu (3), Insufficient memory (3).
  41m       41m     2   default-scheduler           Warning     FailedScheduling    No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: Insufficient cpu (2), Insufficient memory (3).
  40m       36s     136 default-scheduler           Warning     FailedScheduling    No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: Insufficient cpu (1), Insufficient memory (3).
  43m       2s      243 cluster-autoscaler          Normal      NotTriggerScaleUp   pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added)
```

My node pool is set to autoscale with `min: 2`, `max: 5`. And machines (`n1-highmem-8`) in node pool are large enough (52GB) to accommodate this service. But somehow nothing happens:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                 STATUS    AGE       VERSION
gke-dev-default-pool-efca0068-4qq1   Ready     2d        v1.6.2
gke-dev-default-pool-efca0068-597s   Ready     2d        v1.6.2
gke-dev-default-pool-efca0068-6srl   Ready     2d        v1.6.2
gke-dev-default-pool-efca0068-hb1z   Ready     2d        v1.6.2

$ kubectl  describe nodes | grep -A 4 'Allocated resources'
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests     Memory Limits
  ------------  ----------  ---------------     -------------
  7060m (88%)   15510m (193%)   39238591744 (71%)   48582818048 (88%)
--
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
  ------------  ----------  --------------- -------------
  6330m (79%)   22200m (277%)   48930Mi (93%)   66344Mi (126%)
--
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
  ------------  ----------  --------------- -------------
  7360m (92%)   13200m (165%)   49046Mi (93%)   44518Mi (85%)
--
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests     Memory Limits
  ------------  ----------  ---------------     -------------
  7988m (99%)   11538m (144%)   32967256Ki (61%)    21690968Ki (40%)

$ gcloud container node-pools describe  default-pool --cluster=dev
autoscaling:
  enabled: true
  maxNodeCount: 5
  minNodeCount: 2
config:
  diskSizeGb: 100
  imageType: COS
  machineType: n1-highmem-8
  oauthScopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
  serviceAccount: default
initialNodeCount: 2
instanceGroupUrls:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/XXXXXX/zones/europe-west1-b/instanceGroupManagers/gke-dev-default-pool-efca0068-grp
management:
  autoRepair: true
name: default-pool
selfLink: https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/XXXXXX/zones/europe-west1-b/clusters/dev/nodePools/default-pool
status: RUNNING
version: 1.6.2

$ kubectl -n dev get pods -l name=someservice
NAME                      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
someservice-2595684989-h8c5d   0/1       Pending   0          42m
someservice-804061866-f2trc    1/1       Running   0          1h

$ kubectl -n dev describe pod someservice-2595684989-h8c5d

Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubObjectPath   Type        Reason          Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------          -------
  43m       43m     4   default-scheduler           Warning     FailedScheduling    No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: Insufficient cpu (4), Insufficient memory (3).
  43m       42m     6   default-scheduler           Warning     FailedScheduling    No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: Insufficient cpu (3), Insufficient memory (3).
  41m       41m     2   default-scheduler           Warning     FailedScheduling    No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: Insufficient cpu (2), Insufficient memory (3).
  40m       36s     136 default-scheduler           Warning     FailedScheduling    No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: Insufficient cpu (1), Insufficient memory (3).
  43m       2s      243 cluster-autoscaler          Normal      NotTriggerScaleUp   pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added)


$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.2", GitCommit:"477efc3cbe6a7effca06bd1452fa356e2201e1ee", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-04-19T20:33:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.2", GitCommit:"477efc3cbe6a7effca06bd1452fa356e2201e1ee", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-04-19T20:22:08Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that this is a bug with Kubernetes 1.6.2. According to GKE support engineer:

> From the messages "No nodes are available that match all of the
>   following predicates", this seems to be a known issue and the
>   engineers managed to track down the root cause.  It was an issue in
>   cluster autoscaler version 0.5.1 that is currently used in GKE 1.6 (up
>   to 1.6.2). This issue had been fixed already in cluster autoscaler
>   0.5.2, which is included in head for the 1.6 branch.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure instance group autoscaler either is disabled or has proper minimum/maximum number of instances settings.

According to [Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler FAQ](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#is-cluster-autoscaler-compatible-with-cpu-usage-based-node-autoscalers):

> CPU-based (or any metric-based) cluster/node group autoscalers, like
>   GCE Instance Group Autoscaler, are NOT compatible with [Kubernetes
>   Cluster Austoscaler]. They are also not particularly suited to use
>   with Kubernetes in general.

...so it should probably be disabled.

Try:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed describe gke-dev-default-pool-efca0068-grp \
    --zone europe-west1-b
```

Then check out `autoscaler` property. It will be absent if instance group autoscaler is disabled.

To disable it, do:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed stop-autoscaling gke-dev-default-pool-efca0068-grp \
    --zone europe-west1-b
```